# Visual Studio Cordova App not updating on Android device

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-cordova, ripple

When I deploy my app to any Android device I get an old version of the app. I have factory reset the android phone on Kitkat 4.4.4 and have also tried installing on a newer android 5.0 device. I am always getting the same old version cached. When I debug with the ripple emulator I always get the newest changes with no issue.

I have tried adding 'preference name="useBrowserHistory" value="false"' to the config.xml in the solution with no luck. One notable change that has happened is I have moved to a new computer and I did not have this issue on the old one.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to delete the bin and bld folders in your project before you deploy? It might be that for some reason your Android project is not being rebuilt. This should force it.

Comment: I accidentally reproduced your problem. I had a hard to see missing bracket. For some reason an old version continued to be used. After fixing that problem the new version deployed as it should. Maybe a bug in VS2013?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I cant remember exactly what it was on the kitkat device but I know on the android 5.0 device i had more than one profile that had the app installed I had to uninstall it from both user profiles on the tablet. Once i did the new version deployed

Comment: This worked for me, I has a similar problem that the old code was caching in the Ripple emulator. Deleting the bld and bin folders, even though they were empty, fixed the problem.

Comment: I'm having to do this *every* time I make a change. Has anyone else encountered this or found a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the option "Revoke USB debugging authorization" above "USB debugging" to update the authorization Keys in Developer Options in your Android Phone or Emulator.
I use Visual Studio 2015 with Xamarin and works for me.

[image]